# Update deployment fails when same name exists in separate namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've used the following command to update the image run in a deployment:

```
kubectl --cluster websites --namespace production set image 
deployment/mobile-web mobile-web=eu.gcr.io/websites/mobile-web:0.23
```

This worked well until I created a staging namespace mirroring the production environment. In other words the deployment `mobile-web` exists both in the production and staging namespace. Now I get the error:

```
Error from server: the server could not find the requested resource
(get deployments.extensions mobile-web)
```

What am I missing here? Or is the only way to update using a yaml- or JSON-file, which means a bit more work on the CI/CD pipeline? I've tried setting the namespace with:

```
kubectl config set-context production --namespace=production --cluster=websites
```

but to no avail.

Comment: What's the version you're running? (run `kubectl version`)

Comment: Did you create the `deployment/mobile-web` in both `production` and `staging` namespaces? Did you see those two deployments when you do `kubectl get deployment mobile-web --namespace=staging` and `kubectl get deployment mobile-web --namespace=production`?

Comment: I'm using GKE, version 1.4.3. I do see the deployments in the UI using kubectl proxy. I do not have access to a computer at the moment but will verify commands tomorrow and check kubectl version.

Comment: @janetkuo thanks for your concern. The solution was thankfully simpler than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my concern was to kill the current proxy and get new credentials and start the proxy again:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials websites
kubectl proxy --port=8080`

Now either commands work as expected:

`kubectl get deployment mobile-web --namespace=production
kubectl get deployment mobile-web --namespace=staging`

However it doesn't explain why it stopped working in the first place.